# Storage location of PDFs created by LyX on Mac

Tags: lyx, pdf, output

I am using the current Lyx version on an up-to-date Mac and have one issue:

LyX is supposed to store the PDFs in the same folder location as the source file .lyx, however on my Mac the PDFs are always created in a LyX temporary folder and I have to move them manually to the same location as the source file using the Preview app on Mac.

How can I fix this? It worked correctly before, but now it doesn't, I cannot tell exactly since when that is the case.

Best regards, Michael

Comment: With File → Export → PDF (select the one you want) you can select the destination.

Comment: Ok, that's a nice workaround, but shouldn't command-r work the same way?

Comment: Not on my Linux machine. But if you thinks so: [There is a bug tracker for LyX](https://www.lyx.org/trac/wiki/BugTrackerHome)

Comment: @MichaelSeyfried No, because, File → Export will overwrite the PDF of the working directory, whereas as you discovered,  "Document → View PDF" work in a temporary folder to (1) do not infest  your folder with compilation subproducts (.log,.toc...),   but overall to (2) do not overwrite the PDF of the working directory. Is "preview".  Think  that you make a fatal error in a update just before of some important deadline. It is a good idea overwrite directly the existing PDF? Wouldn't it have been better to watch before the preview, without touching this file?